# using xmlDocument.Load vs using http GET for loading xml documents

Tags: c#, xml, web-services, http

so i have been reading around and i cant seem to find a simple enough answer, i have been doing a bit of work with webservices and xml documents being sent around but now im looking to understand something a little better.

`xmlDocument.Load(url)` and `myHttpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest) HttpWebRequest.Create(inURL);`

now there there is obviously a little more code to each of these but i am just giving a brief idea of both so we're all on the same page.

i have used both, and they both work perfectly well, i just dont want to sell myself short when using one over the other (`.Load(url)` has WAY less code to it)

In my instance (testing at the moment) i am using the former to get tiny amounts of data from my web service and using the later to post a fair bit of information back to my web service.

So my question actually is, not really which is better but when would it be desirable to use the one over the other?

Does it make a big difference or just 2 ways to do the same thing without any negatives?

Comment: What is your question? Which is better?

Comment: updated to an actual question.

Comment: This is a candidate for closure because it is primarily opinion based. Personally, I'd go for WAY less code.